# Foreaching only the a href data

Tags: php

I am using simple_html_dom to gather data from another website and I am wondering how I can do a foreach for only the data as an `a` element.

```
$url = 'example.com';
html2 = file_get_html($url);
$download2 = $html2->find('table',1);
$data['ep_table'] = $download2->outertext;
```

The above code returns the following.

```
<table style="height: 341px;">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 31px;">
   <td style="height: 31px; width: 26px;">#</td>
   <td style="height: 31px; width: 196px;">Song</td>
   <td style="text-align: right; height: 31px; width: 82px;">Download</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 62px;">
   <td style="height: 62px; width: 26px;">1</td>
   <td style="height: 62px; width: 196px;">미쳐가지고 (I’m Crazy)</td>
   <td style="text-align: right;height: 62px;width: 82px;">
      <a href="http://example.com/South-Club-im-crazy/"
         target="_blank"
         rel="noopener">
       <strong>
      <button class="button_rbox" title="" type="button">
      <span class="cnt">Download</span>
      </button>
      </strong>
     </a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 31px;">
  <td style="height: 31px; width: 26px;">2</td>
  <td style="height: 31px; width: 196px;">Someday</td>
  <td style="text-align: right; height: 31px; width: 82px;">
     <a href="http://example.com/South-Club-someday/"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener">
       <strong>
        <button class="button_rbox" title="" type="button">
         <span class="cnt">Download</span>
        </button>
       </strong>
      </a>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 93px;">
  <td style="height: 93px; width: 26px;">3</td>
  <td style="height: 93px; width: 196px;">안녕 (Hi/Bye)</td>
  <td style="text-align: right; height: 93px; width: 82px;">
     <a href="http://example.com/South-Club-hi/"
        target="_blank"
        rel="noopener">
       <strong>
       <button class="button_rbox" title="" type="button">
         <span class="cnt">Download</span>
       </button>
       </strong>
     </a>
   </td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 31px;">
   <td style="width: 26px; height: 31px;">4</td>
   <td style="width: 196px; height: 31px;">빗방울 (Raindrop)</td>
   <td style="text-align: right; width: 82px; height: 31px;">
       <a href="http://example.com/South-Club-raindrop/"
          target="_blank" rel="noopener">
         <strong>
         <button class="button_rbox" title="" type="button">
         <span class="cnt">Download</span></button>
         </strong>
      </a>
   </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

How can I do a foreach, which searches only the html of `$data['ep_table']` and not the entire page we're parsing for a `a` element?

I've tried this, with no luck.

```
foreach($data['ep_table']->find('a') as $track){
    print $link = $track->href; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use `find()` on plaintext, not a DOM object. You should do this:

```
$url  = 'example.com';
html2 = file_get_html($url);

foreach( $html2->find('table', 1)->find('a') as $track)
{
    echo $track->href;
}
```

It's also worth pointing out that `find('table', 1)` assumes the target table is the second `<table>` element in the retrieved markup.

Comment: looking at your answer it seems correct, I can't figure out why it was down voted, the only thing I can think of is the sloppy usage of loading `$html2->find('table', 1)->find('a')` this could cause some complications